# What should I do to retrieve the hyperlink to Confluence user's home?

Tags: confluence

Please click this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0OP8.png).
The dog photo in the red rectangle is used as the portrait of the Confluence page author, and the author's portrait(dog photo) is retrieved by below method to be displayed on Confluence page:

```
pic = this.userAccessor.getUserProfilePicture(confluenceUser);
portrait = pic.getDownloadPath();
```

I want user can be directed to the author's home by click the author's portrait (dog photo), however I don't know how to retrieve the URL of the Confluence page author's home as the portrait's hyperlink. 
Could you please help me resolve this question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to link to the users profile, this is the url:

```
http://your.confluence.site/users/viewuserprofile.action?username=USERNAME
```

as described here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/your-user-profile-139549.html